# igraph save plot not working with output filename being an object

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I followed igraph's [saving plot](http://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/tutorial.html#saving-plots) documentation but I need to loop through a list of graphs and it doesn't work:

```
for (f in flist) {
    df <- read.table(f, header=TRUE, sep='\t', quote='', comment.char='')
    png <- paste0(f, '.png')
    g <- graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = FALSE)
    plot(g, png)
}
```

I tried `plot(g, png)`, `plot(g, file=png)`, `plot(g, save=png)`, `plot.igraph(g, png)`, `plot.igraph(g, file=png)`, `plot.igraph(g, save=png)`. None of them works.

```
Error in if (axes) { : argument is not interpretable as logical
```

Or

```
Error in i.parse.plot.params(graph, list(...)) : 
Unknown plot parameters: save
```

Comment: You are checking the python documentation of `igraph`. To save your plot on a file, do it like for any regular R plots. You open the file, call plot and close the device. Like: `png("myfile.png");plot(mygraph);dev.off()` and you'll get `myfile.png` with your plot.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Just looked through the R igraph page:http://igraph.org/r/doc/plot.common.html, didn't find an output argument. Will try your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (f in flist) {
    df <- read.table(f, header=TRUE, sep='\t', quote='', comment.char='')
    png <- paste0(f, '.png')
    g <- graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = FALSE)
    plot(g, png)
    png("/YOUR PATH/XXX.png")
    plot(g)
    dev.off()
}
```